# Removing NAs when mutating a new variable by_group (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, density-plot

I am working on a uni project with EU-SILC data.
I want to create a new variable where all households are assigned to their corresponding housing cost group to create a stacked density plot with the income distribution in relation to housing cost.

I encountered two problems:

1. I cannot create the variable hcost_group because my housing cost variable, which is the basis for assigning the households to the groups has 47 NAs (out of nearly 70.000 observations). I tried many different things to remove the NAs when creating the new variable but I keep getting an error message.
2. As I don't want to generally remove the households for which I dont have housing cost the hcost_group variable will be shorter than my income variable - how can I just for the plot exclude the income of the households for which I don't have a housing cost?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Here is my code (inkl error messages) for creating the variable and the plot:

```
data <- data %>% filter(!is.na(hcost)) %>% group_by(country) %>% 
   mutate(hcost_group = quantcut(share_hc, q=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)))

> 
> ggplot(data=data, aes(x=decile, group=hcost_group, fill=hcost_group)) 
   geom_density(adjust=1.5, position="fill") +
   facet_wrap(~country)+
   xlab("Einkommensdezil")+
   ylab("Anteil der Gruppen nach Wohnkostenbelastung")+
   scale_fill_discrete(name = "Wohnkostenbelastung (Anteil der Wohnkosten am EK)",
                       labels = 
                         c("0-10%", "10-20%","20-30%",
                           "30-40%", "40-100%"))
```

I also tried "na.rm = TRUE", "na.omit()" and also "complete.cases".

EDIT:

- I realized, that I used a wrong variable name (updated the code above) and mutate does not give me an error anymore. Nonetheless, the new variable contains weird numbers. And the plot then contains a lot of NAs.
- Here is a code to reproduce my data:

```
reproduced_data <- 
  structure(
    list(
      country = c("AT",
                  "IT", "DE"),
      income_y = c(9235.28, 29867, 31975),
      hcost = c(558.16,
                105, 466.33),
      tenure = structure(
        c(3L, 5L, 3L),
        .Label = c("1",
                   "2", "3", "4", "5"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      rooms = structure(
        2:4,
        .Label = c("1",
                   "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      dwelling = structure(
        c(4L,
          2L, 3L),
        .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      leak = structure(c(2L,
                         1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      warm = structure(c(1L,
                         1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      bath = structure(
        c(1L,
          1L, 1L),
        .Label = c("1", "2", "3"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      toilet = structure(
        c(1L,
          1L, 1L),
        .Label = c("1", "2", "3"),
        class = "factor"
      ),
      light = structure(c(2L,
                          1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      noise = structure(c(1L,
                          1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      pollution = structure(c(2L,
                              1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      crime = structure(c(2L,
                          1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"),
      share_hc = c(72.5253592744345,
                   4.2187029162621, 17.5010476935106),
      high_hcost = c("1", "0",
                     "0"),
      decile = c(1L, 6L, 6L)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-3L),
    groups = structure(
      list(
        country = c("AT", "DE", "IT"),
        .rows = structure(
          list(1L,
               3L, 2L),
          ptype = integer(0),
          class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                    "vctrs_vctr", "list")
        )
      ),
      row.names = c(NA,-3L),
      class = c("tbl_df",
                "tbl", "data.frame"),
      .drop = TRUE
    ),
    class = c("grouped_df",
              "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

Comment: Please post a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: @akrun just did!

Answer (score 0):

In the first problem, I believe that the issue is not NA... (you can't say without seeing the base), it seems that your quantcut function is missing the correct q parameter. Q waits an integer...

In the second problem make a data frame with the filtered data.

it would also not be possible to make your mutate before the group_by

Answer (score 0):

Does this have something to do with the random `+` before the `mutate()` call?

```
data <- data %>%
    drop_na(hcost) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(
        hcost_group = quantcut(hcost, q = c(.1, .2, .3, .4))
    )
```

I would also ensure that `hcost` is stored as a numeric vector.

Comment: The "+" is not there in the actual code. I copied the code from the console, where pluses are always added on the left. I updated it on my question. `hcost` and `share_hc` are numeric, yes.